# How can I change style of parent elements of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Asp.Net CheckBoxList control and I have a lot of checkboxes inside li elements. I want to change background color of li elements if the checkbox is checked inside it. I tried lots of things with css and jquery but i couldn't do it.

Note: Some of the answers given below are working when I click checkboxes. But when the page is postback, the checked boxes are turning to default view.

```html
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1">
 <li><input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="c1" value="57" /><label for="c1">aaaaaaaaa</label></li>
 <li><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="c2" value="94" /><label for="c2">bbbbbbbbbb</label></li>
 <li><input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="c3" value="121" /><label for="c3">cccccccccc</label></li>
  
  </ul>
```

Some of my tries:

```js
<!-- 1  -->
var ccc = function () {
            $("input:checked").parent("li").css({"color": "white", "background-color": "blue"});
        };
        
        ccc();

        $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", ccc );
        
        
        <!-- 2  -->
        $(":checkbox").click(function(){
   $(":checked").parent().css({"color": "white", "background-color": "blue"});
});
```

```css
/*1*/
li < input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        background-color:aqua;
    }
    
    /*2*/
    li:has( input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
    background: #000;
    border-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you show your try ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** function and [`elem.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.You can add or remove class based on input condition using change event

```js
$(document).on('change','#ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1 input[type=checkbox]',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('checked_class')
   }else{
     $(this).closest('li').removeClass('checked_class')
   }
})
```

```css
.checked_class{
 border:1px solid red;
 /*add your desgin properties*/
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1">
  <li>
  <input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="c1" value="57" />
  <label for="c1">aaaaaaaaa</label>
  </li>
  <li><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="c2" value="94" /><label for="c2">bbbbbbbbbb</label></li>
  <li><input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="c3" value="121" /><label for="c3">cccccccccc</label></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen to the `change` event of the checkbox, then target the parent element (`li`).  My example below simply changes the background of the `li` using [`$.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).  You could add a class using [`.addClass("className")`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

**Edit**: I've updated my answer now you need on load behaviour.

The code below uses a ES6 style function definition using an [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It takes 2 parameters (id, isChecked) and updates the css accordingly.  `toggleStyle` function uses the ternary operator which is equivalent to an `if{} else{}` block.

```js
// on load
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      // pass the id and isChecked to toggleColour
      toggleStyle(this.id, $(this).is(':checked'));    
    });
});

// on change
$('li input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    // pass the id and isChecked to toggleColour
    toggleStyle(this.id, $(this).is(':checked'));   
});

//  ES6 function defn to toggle colour/style
var toggleStyle = (id, isChecked) => 
                     {
                          isChecked ? $('#'+id).parent().css('background', '#ff0') 
                                    : $('#'+id).parent().css('background', '#fff')
                     };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1">
 <li><input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="c1" value="57" /><label for="c1">aaaaaaaaa</label></li>
 <li><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="c2" value="94" checked /><label for="c2">bbbbbbbbbb</label></li>
 <li><input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="c3" value="121" /><label for="c3">cccccccccc</label></li>
  
  </ul>
```

Comment: thanks so much, it's working first but when the page is postback, the checked boxes seems default.

Comment: @ZaferAndaçÖzer Updated answer for onload behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript you could do the following. Using the `change` event listener you can check whether the checkbox has been checked or not. If it evaluates true it means it has been checked by the user. In that case you can get its parent by using [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) object on the element to get manipulate its styles.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const color = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];
inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
      this.parentNode.style.background = color[index]
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With usual Javascript:

```js
window.onload = function a() {
 document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.children[0].checked == true) e.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else e.style.backgroundColor = "";
  e.onchange = a;
 })
}
```

```html
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1">
    <li><input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="c1" value="57" /><label for="c1">aaaaaaaaa</label></li>
    <li><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="c2" value="94" /><label for="c2">bbbbbbbbbb</label></li>
    <li><input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="c3" value="121" /><label for="c3">cccccccccc</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks but however it works when I click the checkboxes, when page is postback the boxes seems as default again. I need theese codes during page load and checking all boxes if they are checked or not.

Comment: OK. This problem is now fixed in my answer (above). Is it working as expected now?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I solved the problem your way (mixing your answers).
I used two functions. One of them is working on page load and controlling all checkboxes if they are checked or not, other is working when a checkbox changes.

```js
             $(document).ready(function () {


                 $("input").each(function (index) {

                     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                         $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
                     }
                     else {
                         $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#eee');
                     }

                 });


             });

             $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1 input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
                 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                     $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
                 }
                 else {
                     $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#eee');
                 }
             });
```